# Opening a System.IO.Packaging.Package from a non-seekable Stream

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.packaging

I am trying to unpack a [`System.IO.Packaging.Package`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Packaging.Package.aspx) that I received from a web server. That is, I am using the [`System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568186.aspx) method and passing it the response stream of a `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`. Unfortunately, this raises a `System.ArgumentException` telling me that it

> Cannot operate on [a] stream that does not support seeking.

Looking at the reference source it turns out that `System.IO.Packaging.Package` uses `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` as its only implementation which in turn uses the internal `ZipArchive` class. And sure enough, the [`ValidateModeAccessStreamStreamingCombinations()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/IO/Zip/ZipArchive.cs,2e063d92407895b0) method raises this exception in line 588 if `stream.CanSeek` is `false` which is the case for the response stream from my `HttpWebResponse`.

However, there is a magic `streaming` parameter which, apparently, is always `false` and gets passed around from the `Package.Open()` method all the way down to `ValidateModeAccessStreamStreamingCombinations()`.

So here's my question: Is there any way to use `Package.Open(Stream)` to construct a `Package` on the fly from a non-seekable stream? Or do I have to cache the stream contents somewhere, for example in a `MemoryStream`? (I really don't want to do that because I'm not interested in the package stream once I have unpacked it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, nevermind. The `streaming` parameter is only intended to *write* a `System.IO.Packaging.Package` on the fly. Starting from [line 954](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/IO/Packaging/Package.cs,954) there are a bunch of "Write-time streaimg API" methods. There also is a [`ThrowIfInStreamingCreation()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/IO/Packaging/Package.cs,04707f0faa798a82) method, which only raises an exception when I try to write a package.

So yeah, I have to cache the non-seekable stream from the `HttpWebResponse` in a `MemoryStream` or a temporary file. No on-the-fly unpacking for me :(